# Multiple checkbox to a sentence before insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I' edit this question with my full coding

Let me post my full code here.

Page1.php

```
<div id="container">
<div class="box">
<form name="form" method="post" action="userbooking2.php">
    <table width="" style="border: 0px solid black" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td><h2>Book a Room Step 1 - Booking Information</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="150px" class="titlestyle">Booked by</td>
                <td width="400px"><span style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FNAME'];  ?></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Title</td>
                <td><span class="hint--right" data-hint="Hint : Organization meeting"><input type="text" name="booking_title" id="booking_title"  maxlength="50" size="50" /></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Date</td>
                <td>From <input type="text" name="booking_start_date" id="booking_start_date"/> to <input type="text" name="booking_end_date" id="booking_end_date"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Time</td>
                <td>From <input name="booking_start_time" id="booking_start_time" value="8:00 AM" /> to <input name="booking_end_time" id="booking_end_time" value="8:30 AM"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Room</td>
                <td><select name="room_type" id="room_type">
                    <option value="none">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="Meeting Room">Meeting Room</option>
                    <option value="Lecture Room">Lecture Room</option>
                    <option value="Computer Lab">Computer Lab</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Participant</td>
                <td><span class="hint--right" data-hint="Hint : Insert number of participants"><input type="text" name="room_participant" id="room_participant"  maxlength="50" size="3" /></span> Persons</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Equipment</td>
                <td><table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="room_facility[]" value="Audio System" />Audio System</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="room_facility[]" value="Projector" />Projector</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="room_facility[]" value="Video Conferencing" />Video Conferencing</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Food & Baverages</td>
                <td><table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="room_food[]" value="Breakfast" />Breakfast</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="room_food[]" value="Tea Break" />Tea Break</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="room_food[]" value="Lunch" />Lunch</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="room_food[]" value="High Tea" />High Tea</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="room_food[]" value="Dinner" />Dinner</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="room_food[]" value="No" />No, thanks</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Additional Info</td>
                <td><span class="hint--right" data-hint="Hint : ."><textarea name="booking_desc" id="booking_desc" style="max-width:400px;" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></span></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Next" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

Page2.php

```
<?php

//now, let's register our session variables
session_register('fname');
session_register('booking_title');
session_register('booking_start_date');
session_register('booking_end_date');
session_register('booking_start_time');
session_register('booking_end_time');
session_register('room_participant');
session_register('room_type');
session_register('booking_facility');
session_register('booking_food');
session_register('booking_desc');

//finally, let's store our posted values in the session variables
$_SESSION['fname']      = $_SESSION['SESS_FNAME'];
$_SESSION['booking_title']  = $_POST['booking_title'];
$_SESSION['booking_start_date'] = $_POST['booking_start_date'];
$_SESSION['booking_end_date']   = $_POST['booking_end_date'];
$_SESSION['booking_start_time'] = $_POST['booking_start_time'];
$_SESSION['booking_end_time']   = $_POST['booking_end_time'];
$_SESSION['room_participant']   = $_POST['room_participant'];
$_SESSION['room_type']      = $_POST['room_type'];
$_SESSION['room_facility']  = /* WHAT TO SEND HERE? */
$_SESSION['room_food']      = $_POST['room_food'];
$_SESSION['booking_desc']   = $_POST['booking_desc'];?>

// Other form process here
```

Page3.php

```
<div id="container">
<div class="box">
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <table width="" style="border: 0px solid black" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td><h2>Book a Room Step 3 - Final</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="150px" class="titlestyle">Booked by</td>
                <td width="400px" ><span style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FNAME'];  ?></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Title</td>
                <td><?php echo $_SESSION['booking_title']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Date</td>
                <td>From <?php echo $_SESSION['booking_start_date']; ?> to <?php echo $_SESSION['booking_end_date']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Time</td>
                <td>From <?php echo $_SESSION['booking_start_time']; ?> to <?php echo $_SESSION['booking_end_time']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Room</td>
                <td><?php echo $_SESSION['room_name']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Participant</td>
                <td><?php echo $_SESSION['room_participant']; ?> Persons</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Equipment</td>
                <td><?php echo $_SESSION['room_facility']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Food & Baverages</td>
                <td><?php echo $_SESSION['room_food']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="titlestyle">Additional Info</td>
                <td><?php echo $_SESSION['booking_desc']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

In page3.php, i want  to view this kind of string "I book Value1, Value2" before store it into the database

Comment: Which part you are getting stuck? Post some code that you have tried.

Comment: Storing data in the form of human language sounds like a poor design to me. How about first creating a table `facility`? You can then use foreign keys to store the user's input, probably saving you a lot of storage space. If you want to output a sentence somewhere, you can build it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 $string = implode(', ', isset($_REQUEST['room_facility']) ? $_REQUEST['room_facility'] : array());

 echo 'I need ' . $string;
```

Then just insert into the database as normal

Comment: Put this at Page1.php or Page2.php ?

Comment: @AdibKhalid: This would be in Page2. The `$_REQUEST` vs `$_POST` applies here as well. See my comment on the answer by @singh